# Understanding UNIX termios VMIN and VTIME

Tags: unix, termios

I am currently working on a simple serial interface on a UNIX based device and cant find a definitive answer to the following:

I am currently trying to determine if a 'pure time read' (VMIN = 0, VTIME >0) will return half way through reading to n_bytes, as the timer is started when read is called, not when the first character is received.

For example, if I send a message to the device on the other end of the serial interface and I want a response I'd attempt the following (pseudo code):

```
m_tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
m_tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 5;                              //i.e. > 0

write(myFileHandle, myData, sizeof(myData));
usleep(sizeof(myData) * 100);                      //assuming 100 us per char to Tx.
read(myFileHandle, myRxData, expectedMinNumBytes);
```

I am unclear as to whether read() would return if the first byte arrived just as the timer was about to expire, or if it would continue until 'expectedMinNumBytes' once the first is received?

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: *"... if it would continue until 'expectedMinNumBytes' once the first is received?"* -- This question makes no sense, since you have specified VMIN as 0.  The first byte already puts the received count past the minimum!

Comment: Great article about VMIN and VTIME: [Understanding UNIX termios VMIN and VTIME](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/termios-vmin-vtime.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pure timed read. If there is available data, the read is immediately satisfied. If there is no data, the timer is started at the time read is called, and the read returns: either because the timer expires (returns 0) or a single byte is available.

Comment: So just to be clear: If no data is available when read() is called, the timer is started and should a single byte arrive during that time only that **one** byte is returned, regardless if other bytes are subsequently received? I am assuming then that these subsequent bytes are stored in the receive buffer and are accessible through another read?

Comment: You could get more than one byte back, assuming a fast baud rate and favorable timing conditions.  No data will be lost (unless there is an overrun), as subsequent **read()** will return the data. .